# MySQL database design for tags

Tags: mysql

I red a lot of articles and examples about tag system implementation, but cannot find answer for some specific cases. I will have more than one table for different notes lets say `NoteTypeOne`, `NoteTypeTwo`, `NoteTypeThree` as I understand I should use **many to many** type of design for tagging so in this case I would create table called `Tags` and table `Note_Tag` for holding references to note and tag. Now my question is should I create multiple reference tables like `NoteTypeOne_Tag`, `NoteTypeTwo_Tag` and multiple tag tables for each note type or just one tag table and one reference table?

Comment: without a bit more info it's hard to be sure, but do you really need separate tables for different types of note? Surely you just have a "Note" table and then have a column "NoteType" which tells you which type it is? That sounds more like a correctly normalised design.

Comment: No dear You don't need to create different tables, you can handled in it in one table by just create a field for (e.g tag_for). Can you please add the table fields may i some one give you some bitter solution

Comment: If number of tags is small and tag values are known beforehand you can just add `SET` type field or even `ENUM` if only one tag per note is allowed. Later you can (with care) alter table definition to edit/add tags.